# Why Netty 4 has no Datagram ServerChannel

Tags: java, udp, netty, datagram

In Netty 4 there is no Nio/Epoll/DatagramServerChannel implementation, so there is no way to create a ServerBootstrap which listens to UDP connections.

So, basically my question is the following:
Why is there no implementation of such a DatagramServerChannel class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel`. See [`QuoteOfTheMomentServer`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/qotm/QuoteOfTheMomentServer.java) as example.